Piecewise exponential hazard function probability for each interval
I am dealing with a piecewise exponential hazard function defined as follows:
Here the rv T is the time to infection.
\begin{equation}
 h(t)= 
\begin{cases}
   \lambda_{1}, \quad  0 < t \leq t_1 \\
   \lambda_{2}, \quad t_{1} < t \leq t_{2}
\end{cases}
 \end{equation}
I am trying to determine the probability that t lies in the 1st interval $(0,t_{1}]$ as well as t lies in the 2nd interval $(t_{1},t_{2}]$.
For the 1st interval$(0,t_1]$ the probability that t lies in the interval is the cdf given by: $1-e^{-\lambda_1 t_{1}}$.
For the 2nd interval $(t_1,t_2]$ the probability that t lies in the interval is the probability of surviving the 1st interval given by $e^{-\lambda_1 t_1}$ multiped by the cdf of the 2nd interval.
I am struggling to understand the form of the cdf for the 2nd interval. Is it the cdf of an exponential distribution truncated at $(t_1,t_2)$ having rate $\lambda_2$? Or is the form of the cdf in the 2nd interval given by: $1-e^{-\lambda_2 (t_2-t_1)}$?
